# Lowest Android Version Possible For SNMP and PPTP

Tags: java, android

I'm having to create a new app for our installers and they currently have an app that they use on Android 5.1. It doesn't use either features mentioned in the title but I'm looking to implement that in the new app. I'm just curious what version do the new phones need at minimum to support an app that allows for both of those to be supported.

SNMP is going to be used to make calls to subscriber modules. Itll have to be able to use both Version 1 and Version 2. It'll be completely equipment based.

The PPTP connection will be only for the app itself. I don't want it to default all traffic the phone is using to that connection. Merely only what calls the app makes to the network. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## PPTP

I'd have to assume there are libraries out there for version of Android that didn't include it natively, it looks like v4.0 is the earliest Android version to include PPTP.

"Android includes a built-in (PPTP and L2TP/IPSec) VPN client, which is sometimes called legacy VPN. Android 4.0 (API Level 14)"

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/vpn

## SNMP

The best thing I can find for SNMP is an app that uses SNMP on Android 2.3.3. Who knows what library or home-rolled code they used to do it, but it looks like you have some "wiggle room" if you're just needing it for Android v5.x.

https://snmp-agent-4a.en.aptoide.com/

Another link that shows the age of SNMP on Android doesn't say what OS version it's talking about, but we can see the images are of fairly ancient phones. It's circumstantial at best, but it looks promising for your project.

https://www.dpstele.com/snmp/monitoring-smartphone-best-practices.php